# Tooltip on react-native-slider

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display tooltip on `react-native-slider`. In google I found lots of libraries but those are supported to `react` only. Any help is appriciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `react-native-slider`, have a look at this [**Pull Request**](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider/pull/48/files), that implements the use of **Thumb** in the slider.

The usage is simple as you pass your own React Component to it.

```js
<Slider createThumbMiddleware={view=>(
            <View style={styles.legendContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{answer}</Text>
                {view}
            </View>
            )} {...// Other Props}/>
```

Therefore you can make your own tooltip component and use it here easily

Comment: I changed my library as per pull request and wrote this code `<Slider  minimumValue={0} maximumValue={100} minimumTrackTintColor='#1fb28a'  maximumTrackTintColor='#d3d3d3' thumbTintColor='#13eba2' createThumbMiddleware={view=>(
                 <View style={styles.legendContainer}>
                     <Text style={styles.title}>Hello from createThumbMiddleware....</Text> 
                 </View>
             )}
            />` but it is neither displaying error nor tooltip.

Comment: Great, any issues?

Comment: You may change the `Hello from createThumbMiddleware....` to `view` as it provides the dyanamic values of the slider. I dont know about the styles, but the rest looks good.

Comment: yes i know first time i used `{view}` which gives dynamic value but it gives same result and also in `Slider.js` `createThumbMiddleware(view)` is not console anything and i think that's why it is not displaying in `<Slider>`.

Comment: I'll try to add a snack expo for it soon.

Comment: There is a problem , since the pull request was old , and they haven't merged their code yet, therefore , you need to add it yourself. The way is create a separate instance of `Slider.js` from their main src and add the `thumbmiddeware` as in the pull request.Since I am busy today, i would be able to focus on it tomorrow.